# Why am I not getting terminal's name within the while loop?

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash

while read line
do
 tty
done < file

i=1
while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do
 tty
let i=$i+1
done
```

> First loop giving output as : not a tty
>
> Second loop giving output as :/dev/pts/14
>
> Why i am not getting terminal name within 1st loop ?

Answer (score 2):

If you read [the `tty` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) you will see it says:

> Print the file name of the terminal connected to **standard input**.

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Since you redirect standard input to be a file then the `tty` command will report that it's not connected to a tty.

Answer (score 2):

The `tty` sees that standard input was directed, because it is inside a loop which has its standard input redirected from a file.

You can achieve what you are trying to do by using a different file descriptor instead of the one that is considered "standard in" (which is file descriptor 0).

```
while IFS= read -r -u 5 line
do
  tty
done 5< file
```

The `-u 5` option tells `read` to read from file descriptor 5.  The `5<` redirection tells Bash to take the contents of file and make it available with  file descriptor 5.

This technique is very useful when you need to avoid capturing standard input in a loop, for instance if you want to have user input.

It also works with process substitution, which allows redirecting the output of an arbitrary command :

```
while IFS= read -r -u 5 line
do
  tty
done 5< <(any_command with arguments)
```

In this case, `<()` is an expression that creates a FIFO special file, executes the stated command and feeds the output of that command as input to the FIFO.  The expression produces a file name (an actual path to the FIFO), and this file is read from, as any other file, for the redirection.

This usually better than using a pipe to the while loop, because the inside of the loop executes in the same context as the rest of the script, avoiding a subshell : variable assignments made inside the loop will therefore be visible once the loop exits.